# Defining id attribute for nested inputs using Rails (5.1) form_with and fields_for (nested form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Rails 5.1 now uses the new `form_with` instead of `form_for` helper.

By using `form_with`, we have to manually set the `id` attributes for HTML input elements, otherwise the `label` elements wouldn't recognize their relative inputs.

For instance:

```
<%= form.label :name %>
<%= form.text_field :name, id: :contact_name %>
```

But I'm using a nested form on a `contact` object with a `phones` attribute, which may contain a list (many) phone numbers:

```
<%= form.fields_for :phones do |phone_fields| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= phone_fields.label :number %>
    <%= phone_fields.text_field :number, id: ???????? %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you look at the HTML output, the generated `label` elements look like this one:

```
  <label for="contact_phones_attributes_2_number">Phone</label>
```

What do I have do set to my `id` attributes for these internal `text_field`?

I "solved" the problem with this (ugly) piece of code:

```
<%= phone_fields.text_field :number,
    id: "contact_phones_attributes_#{phone_fields.index}_number" %>
```

How could it be rewrited?

Comment: Rails 5 still uses form_for().

Comment: @Daniel I'm using Rails 5.1.3 and scaffolding generators are creating `form_with` already. I also read that `form_for` will be deprecated (don't remember the source).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is undergoing a soft deprecation. I was just saying in the meantime you can still use form_for() in Rails 5. That's my understanding of a soft deprecation, the form_for() will not go away until Rails 6 or 6.1 in which deprecation warnings will begin to be issued. I get you want to build it and forget about it, but if you want to complete this feature with form_for() while you resolve your bug with form_with(), you can.

Comment: Yeah @Daniel. I perfectly understood your point. But I think this question is going to be a hot issue in near future. It's going to help people who arrive here. =)